# How to redirect output after a multiline redirect for input in bash?

Tags: bash, ssh, cron, sftp

I have a bash script that uploads a file via SFTP, with a command like this:

```
sshpass -pABC123 sftp user@host.com  << !
   cd data
   put /path/file.txt
   bye
!
```

I get an email notification from my bash script when the process is complete. I would like to capture the actual output from this command (the responses from the server or errors from sshpass) into a variable or text file and include it in my email as well.

What are my options to redirect the output. I know I can place commands into $() to capture their output, and I can use >> as well, but with the multiline input, I dont think these will work...

I have tried this:

```
SFTP_RESULT = (    
   sshpass -pABC123 sftp user@host.com  << !
       cd data
       put /path/file.txt
       bye
    ! 
)
```

And I have also tried:

```
sshpass -pABC123 sftp user@host.com  << ! >> /file.txt
```

and

```
sshpass -pABC123 sftp user@host.com >> /file.txt << !
```

All of these simply return back my commands which I am sending to the remote server. I dont see any of the responses from the server. When I run the script form the command line with any of the above, I see the responses on the screen.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I have accepted the answer from *Lars Kotthoff* even though its not perfect, but based on his answer and our discussion in the comments to his answer I figured it out. This is what I did:

First I moved the sftp commands to an external file called "sftp_commands"

```
echo $(cat sftp_commands | sshpass -pABC123 sftp user@host.com 2>&1) >> sftp.log
```

For some reason that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirects work:

```
$ cat << ! > /tmp/foo
> foo
> bar
> !
$ cat /tmp/foo 
foo
bar
```

Comment: When I do this, my output file contains only the commands which I sent into the other server. (It repeats cd data, put /path.., etc) It does not show me the response from the server. When I run it from the command line it seems the responses still go to stdout.

Comment: I got it figured out based on your suggestions, thanks Lars, see above.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want to use an [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) script.  Expect should be available for your operating system and distribution.

Barring that, see if you can use `scp`, which is often available on servers that also have sftp enabled.  It may be much easier just to:

```
scp /path/file.txt user@example.com:data/
```

Note that it's probably a better idea to set up SSH public keys rather than use sshpass.

Comment: unfortunately the admins of the remote server wont do the public keys. maybe they don't know how or maybe they don't understand that its the safest, but they stonewalled me on it. it would have saved me hours of aggravation, but I gave up arguing with them, and I am just trying to move on. I dont see how I can preset the password with scp. I will look into expect... Thanks

Comment: If you have SSH access to a shell on the server, you can probably set up your public key yourself.  Just take the ~/.ssh/id_[dr]sa.pub file from the machine initiating the connections and place it in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote server.  (This probably won't be possible if your only access to the server is chrooted.)